# generic method in abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I have the following abstract base class in which i have an abstract method. I need to know how to implement this abstract method in the child classes. The problem is how do I declare a class whose base is SomeBaseClass in Class B.

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected abstract void Add<T>(T number) where T : SomeBaseClass;
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void Add<T>(T number)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: may you implement a constraint to the class instead of the method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want the base class to have a type parameter, not a specific method:

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : SomeBaseClass
{
    protected abstract void Add(T number);
}

public class B : A<C> {

    protected void Add(C number) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is there any way to implement this without changing class A?

Comment: @stech, if you want subclasses to control the type arguments, the type parameters belong on the class.  If you want *callers* of the method to control the type arguments, the type parameters belong on the method.

Comment: No- you can't constrain a method's type parameters in a class deriving from that method's containing class.  That would be a change of the method signature.